# Rational, integers and probability

Tags: probability

> Consider $\sqrt{n}$, where $n$ is an integer and $1\le n \le 10$. How many of these ten numbers are irrational?

---

> An integer $n$ is randomly chosen from $1$ to $k^2$, where $k$ is an integer. What is the probability that $n$ is a perfect square?

For the first one I had figured out it was $7$ irrationals numbers but did not know how to prove the second question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: the perfect squares from $1$ to $k^2$ are $1^2, 2^2, \ldots, k^2$.